# Organic Groups admin has can't edit roles and permissions in groups

Tags: organic-groups, users

I have a user who is an "administrator member" of a group called "Fancy group".

"Administrator members" of this group have permission to administer roles and permissions within the group.

[image]

but my user, an administrator of Fancy group, can only view the roles and permissions, not administer them:

[image]

Is this a bug in OG or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happen when you click on People while logged in with that role ?

Comment: I get an interface for adding people to/removing people from the group, as well as assigning roles to people. I can administer people, but not roles or permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably that the group doesn't have it's own role/permission settings. It's using the global og roles/permissions, and so the settings within the group are all read-only.

One of the fields you can add to group entities via the OG Fields settings is a "Group Roles and Permissions" field. Once that field is added, you can edit the group entity and set the field to "Override default roles and permissions".

Once that's done, the group will have it's own permissions, and users within the group who have permission to edit the groups permissions will be able to.

Comment: Nice, would have taken me awhile to find this. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to checkout the [organic groups documentation on roles & permissions](http://drupal.org/node/2014959).